# Differences in .s assembly between GCC and mingw: How to compile QBE output on windows?

Tags: assembly, gcc, mingw, abi

I want to use QBE (a simple compiler backend) which I have compiled for windows.

To try it out I wanted to compile the example file `hello.ssa`:

```
function w $add(w %a, w %b) {              # Define a function add
@start
    %c =w add %a, %b                   # Adds the 2 arguments
    ret %c                             # Return the result
}
export function w $main() {                # Main function
@start
    %r =w call $add(w 1, w 1)          # Call add(1, 1)
    call $printf(l $fmt, ..., w %r)    # Show the result
    ret 0
}
data $fmt = { b "One and one make %d!\n", b 0 }
```

I compiled it with QBE:

```
> qbe.exe -o out.s hello.ssa
```

Which gave me the following `out.s` file:

```
.text
add:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl %edi, %eax
    addl %esi, %eax
    leave
    ret
.type add, @function
.size add, .-add
/* end function add */

.text
.globl main
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl $1, %esi
    movl $1, %edi
    callq add
    movl %eax, %esi
    leaq fmt(%rip), %rdi
    movl $0, %eax
    callq printf
    movl $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
.type main, @function
.size main, .-main
/* end function main */

.data
.balign 8
fmt:
    .ascii "One and one make %d!\n"
    .byte 0
/* end data */

.section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Then I wanted to create an executable with MinGW:

```
> gcc -o hello.exe out.s
out.s: Assembler messages:
out.s:9: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
out.s:9: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `a'
out.s:10: Warning: .size pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
out.s:10: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `a'
out.s:28: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
out.s:28: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `m'
out.s:29: Warning: .size pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef: ignored.
out.s:29: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `m'
out.s:39: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `-'
```

This is the output I get when running the example. It compiles fine with GCC on wsl:

```
wsl gcc -o hello out.s
```

But the MinGW gcc compiler it does not seem to understand the assembly.

I noticed that the default .s output for a simple C Hello, World is also different between the two compilers. E.g:

```
gcc -S hello.c
```

gives a different .s file depending on which platform is used.

So what compiler/compiler flag/assembler can I use to get machine code from my qbe-generated out.s file on windows?

Secondly, I think QBE only supports the system-V ABI at the moment, so is it correct that I need to link against system-V stub functions instead of the CRT library functions, or does the mingw CRT already use the system-V ABI?

Comment: The code is for the ELF format. You tried to assemble for PE (windows). Although it is not too difficult to filter out the incompatible directives.

Comment: MinGW GCC uses the Windows x64 ABI so code it generates is able to call standard Windows library functions, and be called by them.

Comment: Where is the .s format documented (the windows one)? Which directives can I use? Also, I tried compiling a mingw-gcc generated .s file with clang and vice versa. Both produced minor errors. This means that they are mutually incompatible.

Comment: @PeterCodes So if I use __attribute__((sysv_abi)) to create bridging functions with a C compiler wrapping the underlying functions of the stdlib, will that work? I am new to this and just want to try shit out.

Comment: How about you use WSL2 and just go for linux toolchain?

Comment: Where is the fun in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it compile by patching QBE to not emit .size and .type in its assembly output. So when I compile:

```
function w $add(w %a, w %b) {             
@start
    %c =w add %a, %b                   
    ret %c                             
}
export function w $main() {                
@start
    %r =w call $add(w 1, w 1)          
    call $sysv_printf(l $fmt, ..., w %r) # Calling my wrapper
    ret 0
}
data $fmt = { b "One and one make %d!\n", b 0 }
```

with QBE I get:

```
.text
add:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl %edi, %eax
    addl %esi, %eax
    leave
    ret
/* end function add */

.text
.globl main
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl $1, %esi
    movl $1, %edi
    callq add
    movl %eax, %esi
    leaq fmt(%rip), %rdi
    movl $0, %eax
    callq sysv_printf
    movl $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
/* end function main */

.data
.balign 8
fmt:
    .ascii "One and one make %d!\n"
    .byte 0
/* end data */
```

I have created a C wrapper:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int __attribute__((sysv_abi)) sysv_printf( const char *restrict fmt, ... ) {
    printf("Called with %s", fmt);
    assert(strcmp(fmt, "One and one make %d!\n") == 0);
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int smth = va_arg(ap, int);
    printf("%d\n", smth);
    va_end(ap);
    printf("Finish");
}
```

So if i run these steps in my batchfile

```
call qbe -o out.s hello.ssa
call gcc -c out.s
call gcc -c stub.c
call gcc -S -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables stub.c
call gcc -o main.exe stub.o out.o
```

I get an executable main.exe.

However when I run it something does not work with the variadic arguments:

```
Called with One and one make %d!
```

The format string works, but the integer does not seem to be passed correctly.
If I check the return value:

```
> echo %errorlevel%
-1073741819
```

Which is probably due to my program causing a segmentation fault.

Edit:
Compiling with clang gives the following error message:

```
stub.c:17:5: error: 'va_start' used in System V ABI function
   17 |     va_start(ap, fmt);
      |     ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\17\include\stdarg.h:33:29: note: expanded from macro 'va_start'
   33 | #define va_start(ap, param) __builtin_va_start(ap, param)
      |                             ^
1 error generated.
```

So I think it is not possible to use system-V ABI variadics on windows. But GCC could also have a nicer error message. Maybe I will trying to cross the ABI canyon with a bridge made from assembly instead of using a C compiler, but let's leave it at that.

Comment: If I read the assembly correctly, qbe puts the integer in %esi.

Comment: Yeah, the asm `main` from QBE looks correct, same as what GCC or Clang would emit for calling `sysv_abi` functions `add` and `printf`.  Perhaps there's a GCC bug in how it implements `__attribute__((sysv_abi))`?  I seem to recall seeing a bug with that attribute in either GCC or Clang in some stack overflow question in the past couple years.  Does it help to define `int sysv_printf(const char *fmt,  int arg)` so it's not variadic?  Also, you forgot to return a value, but that's not a showstopper in C (unlike C++); it's only UB if the caller actually uses the retval from such a function.

Comment: If it faults, find out where by running it under a debugger.

Comment: It does work for non variadic functions. So, does gcc not respect the sysv_abi attribute when I use stdarg.h macros? How do you fix that? >Does it help to define int sysv_printf(const char *fmt,  int arg) so it's not variadic? Yes it does fix it.

Comment: You can report a GCC bug on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/, preferably with a [mcve] that's as minimal as possible, like an asm caller.  Also preferably if you can identify what's actually wrong in GCC's code-gen to be sure it's a GCC bug, not a problem with the library you're linking against.  Godbolt actually does have MinGW-w64 GCC installed; https://godbolt.org/z/rWvdK86WK

Comment: Yeah, MinGW GCC makes broken asm here.  It stores a small integer with `movl    $8, 40(%rsp)`, then treats it as a pointer with `movq    40(%rsp), %rax` / `movl    (%rax), %edx`.  (Another instruction also stored `$48` to `44(%rsp)`, the high 32 bits of that qword it's loading.)  I tested this on my Linux desktop, copy/pasting the `.S` file from https://godbolt.org/z/W6fxzYGY6 and tweaking the `main` caller to work on Linux (just commenting the `# call __main`), and putting the static data in `.rodata` (I left Godbolt's filters on so there weren't `.section .rdata` and `.text` directives.)

Comment: Is it it really a bug in GCC or is it a bug in MinGW? Since it probably only is wrong if the host OS is not using system V so the va_list macros don't work correctly. So should I report a bug to MinGW (I do not know where), or GCC? Also, since you have a Linux machine (or I can try with WSL) you can check what happens if you use an ms_abi decorated function with varaidics. Also note my edit regarding clang.

Comment: It's a bug in GCC.  MinGW is the packaging including libraries of GCC targeting Windows built to run on Windows, but the actual compiler doing the code-gen is GCC.  Also, https://godbolt.org/z/axeozqqeo reproduces it with `gcc -O2 -mabi=ms` on Linux GCC, but not with just a `__attribute__((ms_abi)) int ms_printf(char *fmt, ...)` declaration for the function we want to call.  In that case the va_arg stuff optimizes away.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/ is where you can report MinGW bugs.  e.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/970/ is one about `stdarg.h` being included in both `mingw-w64-headers` and `mingw-w64-gcc`, presumably with identical contents.  Anyway, check for duplicates there and on GCC's bugzilla, but if you don't find any, probably report on the main bugzilla.  (Or maybe both, and have each include a link to the other.)